# How to remove duplicate class template in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio

When I select menu add - new item in my project on solution explorer in Visual Studio 2015 and want select new class template i see [duplication this template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VtBm.png). How to fix it?

Comment: It is not a duplicate but 2 different templates, one of which was "forgotten" to be given a proper name. It happens in combination with some of those xamarin -driven project types I think.

Comment: maybe so, but any this template create class file that contains identical code

Comment: Then you are more lucky than I am - for me, they both have same name and one produces android specific code and the other the code I want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besha,

I've encountered the same problem, which as I'm sure is caused by Xamarin item templates. These templates use the same definitions as native VS studio templates, e.g.:

Name Package="{FAE04EC1-301F-11d3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}" ID="2245"

Thus, when VS shows you the items it ends up with duplicate names.

To fix the problem I've scanned all the template files (*.vstemplate) containing the mentioned above GUID and replaced the Name element with a text that suites my needs. E.g. for the Xamarin class I've changed it to be:
    Xamarin C# class 
instead of Package=".....

Note, that VS uses caching of templates and the caching is different for VS native templates and third party templates. In case of Xamarin, there will be ZIP files containing the templates and cached files with templates extracted from the archives. E.g.:

c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin\Xamarin\3.11.785.0\T\~IC\IT\Code\GeneralClass.zip\

will contain the extracted templates, while the original archive is there:
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin\Xamarin\3.11.785.0\T\IT\Code\GeneralClass.zip

Your goal is to find the non-cached templates and change the Name element there.

Once you've found and fixed the name element, close Visual Studio, launch the command prompt as administrator, go to the
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE folder
and run the following command:

```
devenv /installvstemplates
```

It will take a while.

Hopefully, after that you won't see duplicated class items.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks very much, this is helped me fix my trouble =)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Xamarin/Xamarin Studio installed (and don't use it), you can also just simply uninstall it, removing the class templates.  Unity by default installs Xamarin Studio, and I simply remove it as I develop Unity projects with Visual Studio.