# Duplicate Add new item options in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Duplicate Add new Item Entries.

[image: A Photo of the Problem]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate class template in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32677623/how-to-remove-duplicate-class-template-in-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: Also see [this](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Blogs/Tool-Tracker/2012/08/Cleaning-Up-the-Template-Lists.aspx) and [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f58d7714-1c37-4537-9b3c-657ee6fc8fbf/removing-duplicate-installed-project-templates-in-visual-studio-2010?forum=vseditor), I haven't find one for VS2017, but those could give you some ideas.

Comment: I guess the problem is with Xamarin but it is to complicated to mess with I'm afraid I could mess it up and ejnd up with a corrupted installation of visual studio